# Make function with any variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to javascript and have some trouble to get this scenario to work: I have generated elements `#someotheridx` where x is 1 for the first and grows for each added element, so `#someotherid1` `#someotherid2` `#someotherid3` and so on.

I want to replace it with an input field `#someidx`. I can get it to work for any element by using the code below (called onclick of a button), but I would need to make like 100 of them (replacing the 1s with 2s and so on) so if the user created 100 elements it still works.

How can I make one function so that it works for all elements? Using while or if?

```
function aaa1()
{
    var input = $('<input>', { val: $("#someid1").text(), class:"someclass",
                              type: "text" });
    $("#someotherid1").replaceWith(input);
    input.select();  
}

function aaa2()
{
    var input = $('<input>', { val: $("#someid2").text(), class:"someclass",
                              type: "text" });
    $("#someotherid2").replaceWith(input);
    input.select();  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one function will make your scenario to work.

call the following function with the index/number of the element and it will do the magic for you :)

```
function CommonFunction(index)
{
    var input = $('<input>', { val: $("#someid"+index).text(), class:"someclass",
                              type: "text" });
    $("#someotherid"+index).replaceWith(input);
   input.select();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't get easier than that. :)